# ggplot - how to create axis ticks if I have no actual data in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where I am using just `geom_hline`. I use it just to illustrate the example and I don't need any actual data. This is the code:

```
ggplot()+
 geom_hline(yintercept = .3)
```

However, I want my x-axis to show ticks and text labels from 1 to 12. I just can't seem to find a way to do it - using `breaks` within `scale_x_continuous` seems to have no effect whatsoever. So then how can I make the plot that I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_discrete` with `limits` and `labels`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = .3) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(c(1:12)), labels = as.character(c(1:12)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>